# Combining Excel Sheets (VBA) With An Exception

Tags: excel, vba

This macro combines all the worksheets in my workbook.
I would like to add an exception to my macro to pick up data from all worksheets except for the one named ***PO-SMS***.

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xTCount As Variant
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    xTCount = Application.InputBox("The number of title rows", "", "1")
    If TypeName(xTCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(xTCount) Then
        MsgBox "Only can enter number", , "For Excel"
        GoTo LInput
    End If
    Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xWs.Name = "Combined"
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
               Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Where are you having issues?

Comment: The macro as it is functions well. Where and how do I add the exception: 'except for worksheet named PO-SMS'? That's the question.

Comment: `If Worksheets(i).Name <> "PO-SMS"` and change to `For i = 1`.

Comment: No 'GoTo' or 'Then' necessary?

Comment: No, because the logic will ignore that worksheet.

Comment: Complie error: Syntax error

Comment: Well you need a `Then` and an `End If`... sorry misread your question.

Comment: Don't know how, still a beginner.

Comment: You used an `IF THEN statement` 7 lines above the `For i =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xTCount As Variant
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    xTCount = Application.InputBox("The number of title rows", "", "1")
    If TypeName(xTCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(xTCount) Then
        MsgBox "Only can enter number", , "For Excel"
        GoTo LInput
    End If
    Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xWs.Name = "Combined"
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name <> "PO-SMS" Then

        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
               Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
    Else
    'do nothing

    End If
Next


End Sub
```